# MySQL update query slow with where on primary key

Tags: mysql

I have table which has 10 million records, I am using MySQL 5.6 innodb engine. It's transactional table. I am trying to update row by using primary key in where clause. I am trying update two column out of them one has index and one is non index column. My query looks something like this

```
Update table 
set index column = 1234, nonindexcolumn  = 'test' 
where primary key = 12345678
```

It's taking more than 30 secs. When I removed index from index column its updating faster but I need index on that column.

Comment: Hi, this might be of interest https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14010

Comment: If you just do this `update table set nonindexcolumn = 'test' where primarykey = 12345678`, is that any faster?

Comment: You could try telling MySQL to not use an index, but that could actually make the update slower. `UPDATE table USE INDEX() SET column = 1234 WHERE pkey = 1234` That may work.. But it sounds to me that your real problem is that the index is very large and is being updated when you update the table. You may be able to increase performance of the index by doing an `OPTIMIZE` or an `ANALYZE` on the table. These deal with either rebuilding or cleaning up your table and its indexes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html